# How convert Mon.YY to YearNN

Tags: datetime, stata

I want to convert a string in Stata like Jan.01 (string, format %9s) to a datetime like 2001m1 (int, format %tm)

````
fecha   ID  tc_t3
Jan.01  1   575
Feb.01  1   575
Mar.01  1   580
Apr.01  1   .
May.01  1   605
Jun.01  1   615
Jul.01  1   630
```
````

Answer (score 1):

This falls entirely within cases documented by `help datetime`

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str6 fecha
"Jan.01"
"Feb.01"
"Mar.01"
"Apr.01"
"May.01"
"Jun.01"
"Jul.01"
end


* no dates in 1999 or earlier 
. gen mdate = monthly(fecha, "M20Y")

* any dates in latter part of 20th century 
. gen MDATE = monthly(fecha, "MY", 2025)

. format mdate MDATE %tm

. list 

     +--------------------------+
     |  fecha    mdate    MDATE |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | Jan.01   2001m1   2001m1 |
  2. | Feb.01   2001m2   2001m2 |
  3. | Mar.01   2001m3   2001m3 |
  4. | Apr.01   2001m4   2001m4 |
  5. | May.01   2001m5   2001m5 |
     |--------------------------|
  6. | Jun.01   2001m6   2001m6 |
  7. | Jul.01   2001m7   2001m7 |
     +--------------------------+
```